# Semicolon inside if statement

Tags: c++, c

I was reading a page about IPC: Message Queue, that's when i came across the following section of code.

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>; 
#include <sys/msg.h>; 

... 


key_t key; /* key to be passed to msgget() */ 
int msgflg /* msgflg to be passed to msgget() */ 
int msqid; /* return value from msgget() */ 

...
key = ...
msgflg = ...

if ((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg)) == &ndash;1) //*****Semicolon inside IF*****
  {
    perror("msgget: msgget failed");
    exit(1);
   } else
    (void) fprintf(stderr, &ldquo;msgget succeeded");
...
```

The above code illustrates msgget() function. Whatever, in the above code the semicolon inside If statement is allowed by syntax? Does it have any meaning?

Comment: `&ndash;` is an HTML special character.

Comment: `&ndash;1` means `–1` and `&ldquo;` is `"`.

Comment: Looks like some kind of weird copy and paste error when the page was created, it's worth pointing out that `&ndash;` is `–` (not `-`) and `&ldquo;` is `“` (not `"`), so even if these were dereferenced it still wouldn't be valid code.

Comment: Just to clarify the comments above: this is broken layout on [that page](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node25.html), not a C feature.

Comment: Note that since C++17, using ; inside if statements is permitted. This example is broken html, and still would not be legal, but I was directed here by google. The new C++17 syntax allows the declaration of a scoped variable to be separated from a test against that variable's value, not just zero; eg `if (int file=open(...); file!=-1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are HTML special characters and they are not a part of C++.
This was a transposition error.
The code should read:

```
if ((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg)) == -1)
  {
    perror("msgget: msgget failed");
    exit(1);
   } else
    (void) fprintf(stderr, "msgget succeeded");
```